# Перенос данных из excel (xlsx) в .dbf при помощи Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, excel, delphi-7, dbf

Сразу говорю я начинающий программист на Delphi. У меня задача автоматизировать перенос или копирование данных из таблицы excel(есть готовая таблица) в dbf(есть пустой шаблон, который должен заполнить). Вот мой сырой код, помогите советами

```
procedure TForm1.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
 label end_pr;
 var SearchFiles:TsearchRec;
     r,i:integer;
     str3,str1,str2,str4,str5,str6,str7,str8,str9,str10,str11,str12,str13,str14,str15,str16,str17,str18,str19,str20,str21,str22,str23,str24,str25,str26,str27,str28,str29,str30:string;
begin
  CopyFile('D:\Form_M70\m70.dbf',false);
  ChDir('D:\Form_M70\Dbf');
  with table1 do begin
   tablename:='M70.dbf'
   tabletype:=ttfoxpro;

  end;
  table1.Open;
  table1.Edit;
  if FindFirst ('d:\pereg\mgsp\*.xls',faAnyFile,SearchFiles) = 0 then begin

         // ShowMessage(SearchFiles.Name);
          XLApp:=CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
          xlbook:=xlapp.workbooks.add('d:\pereg\mgsp\'+SearchFiles.Name);
          XLApp.Visible:=false;
          xlsheet:=xlbook.worksheets[1];
          xlsheet.Activate;
          r:=2; // строка с которой будет читать!
          str1:=XLApp.ActiveSheet.Cells[r,1].Text;
          str2:=XLApp.ActiveSheet.Cells[r,2].Text;
          str3:=XLApp.ActiveSheet.Cells[r,3].Text;
          str4:=XLApp.ActiveSheet.Cells[r,4].Text;
          str5:=XLApp.ActiveSheet.Cells[r,5].Text;
      str6:=XLApp.ActiveSheet.Cells[r,6].Text;
          str7:=XLApp.ActiveSheet.Cells[r,7].Text;
      str8:=XLApp.ActiveSheet.Cells[r,8].Text;      
      str9:=XLApp.ActiveSheet.Cells[r,9].Text;
      str10:=XLApp.ActiveSheet.Cells[r,10].Text;
      str11:=XLApp.ActiveSheet.Cells[r,11].Text;
      str12:=XLApp.ActiveSheet.Cells[r,12].Text;
      str13:=XLApp.ActiveSheet.Cells[r,13].Text;
      str14:=XLApp.ActiveSheet.Cells[r,14].Text;
      str15:=XLApp.ActiveSheet.Cells[r,15].Text;
      str16:=XLApp.ActiveSheet.Cells[r,16].Text;
      str17:=XLApp.ActiveSheet.Cells[r,17].Text;
      str18:=XLApp.ActiveSheet.Cells[r,18].Text;
      str19:=XLApp.ActiveSheet.Cells[r,19].Text;
      str20:=XLApp.ActiveSheet.Cells[r,20].Text;
      str21:=XLApp.ActiveSheet.Cells[r,21].Text;
      str22:=XLApp.ActiveSheet.Cells[r,22].Text;
      str23:=XLApp.ActiveSheet.Cells[r,23].Text;
      str24:=XLApp.ActiveSheet.Cells[r,24].Text;
      str25:=XLApp.ActiveSheet.Cells[r,25].Text;
      str26:=XLApp.ActiveSheet.Cells[r,26].Text;
      str27:=XLApp.ActiveSheet.Cells[r,27].Text;
      str28:=XLApp.ActiveSheet.Cells[r,28].Text;
      str29:=XLApp.ActiveSheet.Cells[r,29].Text;
      str30:=XLApp.ActiveSheet.Cells[r,30].Text;

          table1.Append;
          while str1<>'' do begin;
                 table1.Edit;
                 table1.Fields[0].AsString:=copy(trim(str1),1,5)+'0';
                 table1.Fields[1].AsString:=copy(trim(str1),7,5)+'9';
                 table1.Fields[2].AsString:=copy(trim(str2),1,5)+'0';
                 table1.Fields[3].AsString:=copy(trim(str2),7,5)+'9';
                 table1.Fields[4].AsString:=trim(str3);
                 table1.Fields[5].AsString:=trim(str4);
                 table1.Fields[6].AsString:='';
                 table1.Fields[7].AsString:='';
                 table1.Fields[8].AsString:=trim(str4);
                 table1.Post;
                 r:=r+1;
                 str1:=XLApp.ActiveSheet.Cells[r,1].Text;
                 str2:=XLApp.ActiveSheet.Cells[r,2].Text;
                 str3:=XLApp.ActiveSheet.Cells[r,3].Text;
                 str4:=XLApp.ActiveSheet.Cells[r,4].Text;
                 table5.Append;
          end; // конец цикла по найденным файлам
          xlapp.quit;
          xlapp:=unassigned;
          freeandnil(xlapp);
     //end;  // êîíåö öèêëà ïî íàéäåííûì ôàéëàì
     FindClose(SearchFiles);
  end
  else begin
     showmessage ('Файл не найден. Работа программы завершена '):
     goto end_pr;
     end;

  messagebox(0,'Áàçà côîðìèðîâàíà!','Èíôîðìàöèÿ',0);
  table5.close;
  Button1.Enabled:=true;
  BitBtn1.Enabled:=false;
 end_pr:
 end;
```

Comment: Ваш код не работает? или чем вам помочь? https://yadi.sk/i/GsLmNv0egU4uAg вот то что сразу бросилось в глаза... но компилятор должен был орать на это благим матом... =)

Comment: Исправил,но деле не в этом. Да, код не работает!

Comment: Что значит не работает? выдает ошибку? не создает файл? не считывает данные? Больше подробностей =) Ставить делфи7 чтоб глянуть что у вас там происходит - никакого желания, использовать то что у меня стоит - ничем не поможет вам =)

Comment: *помогите советами* Range можно сразу копировать в динамический массив - на выходе будет двумерный массив значений (или формул - что попросишь...). Это намного быстрее и компактнее, чем хренова гора скалярных переменных.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую, но можете дать один пример на этом коде?

Comment: Есть ли  код как пример переноса данных из excel в dbf

Comment: @AskhatUrpebay есть, на php, поможет? Перечитайте третий комментарий, дополните вопрос, и у вас будет шанс получить ответ, пока вопрос еще не закрыли....